# как уменьшить код и тд?

Tags: python

Изучаю питон и программирование 3 день, хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение по поводу кода. Может дадите советы, как уменьшить код и тд, буду благдарен

```
q = 0
print("Типа психологический тест на созависимость")
print("Отвечайте только Да или Нет")
x = input("Вам легко знакомиться с людьми?: ")

if x == "Да":
    q += 1
elif x == "Нет":
    q += 0
else:
    print("Такого варианта ответа нет!")
c = input("Вы бы хотели быть в центре внимания других людей?: ")

if c == "Да":
    q += 1
elif c == "Нет":
    q += 0
else:
    print("Такого варианта ответа нет!")
v = input("Вам трудно принимать решения?: ")

if v == "Да":
    q += 1
elif v == "Нет":
    q += 0
else:
    print("Такого варианта ответа нет!")
b = input("Вы часто тревожитесь?: ")

if b == "Да":
    q += 1
elif b == "Нет":
    q += 0
else:
    print("Такого варианта ответа нет!")

if q == 5:
    print("Вы созависимый человек")
elif q == 4:
    print("Вы созависимый человек")
elif q == 3:
    print("Вы местами созависимы")
elif q == 2:
    print("Вам стоит поработать над собой")
elif (q == 1 or q == 0):
    print("Вы несозависимы!")
```

Comment: для чего вы делаете `q += 0` ?

Comment: "elif (q == 1 or q == 0):" или "elif q <= 1:" или "else:". Циклы изучили?

Comment: "и тд" - Лучше уточнить, что это значит, ведь никто не знает, что у вас в голове. На зарубежном stackoverflow за такой заголовок автоматом минус ставят. За это я и люблю русский стак, тут любому новичку помогут.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Например так:

```
...
...
questions = ("Вам легко знакомиться с людьми?: ",
             "Вы бы хотели быть в центре внимания других людей?: ",
             "Вам трудно принимать решения?: ",
             ...)

for question in questions:
    answer = input(question)
    if answer == "Да":
        q += 1
        continue
    if answer != "Нет":
        print("Такого варианта ответа нет!")
    
...
...
```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Ваша программа реагирует на все вопросы одним и тем же образом. Почему не заготовить все вопросы в виде кортежа и обработать их в цикле?
2. Когда ответ был **"Да"**, увеличиваем значение счетчика, и командой `continue` продолжаем с обработкой следующего ответа (игнорируя оставшиеся команды в цикле для текущего ответа).
3. Когда команда `continue` не исполнилась, значит, ответ не был **"Да"**. Ответ **"Нет"** вообще игнорируем, потому что нет чего делать, только для неправильного ответа выведем сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 5):

Вместо блока команд

```
if q == 5:
    print("Вы созависимый человек")
elif q == 4:
    print("Вы созависимый человек")
elif q == 3:
    print("Вы местами созависимы")
elif q == 2:
    print("Вам стоит поработать над собой")
elif (q == 1 or q == 0):
    print("Вы несозависимы!")
```

вы можете заранее приготовить словарь с ответами и затем применить только один `print()`:

```
answers = {0: "Вы несозависимы!",
           1: "Вы несозависимы!",
           2: "Вам стоит поработать над собой",
           3: "Вы местами созависимы",
           4: "Вы созависимый человек",
           5: "Вы созависимый человек",
          }

print(answers[q])   # ответ выбирается для ключа q
```

Answer (score 4):

Совет на будущее, лучше называть переменные со смыслом, а не просто буквы. Если будет большой проект, то вы просто запутаетесь. Также в конце  где вы проверяете балы, я бы использовал **switch**  вместо **if**, т.к. это удобнее. Ну и в конце, где вы пишете **elif(q==1 or q==0)** можно поступить двумя вариантами: 1) вместо этого просто написать **else**: , 2) написать так **elif(q<=1)**

Comment: А разве в python есть switch?

Comment: Теперь да, с версии 3.10 switch присутствует в python

Comment: У меня (Linux, все стоит "по умолчанию") до сих пор 2.7.17 (а python3 -- 3.6.9). Подозреваю, что эта ситуация не изменится еще много лет.

Comment: А поставить новую версию вообще никак не получается? Вроде как можно новую поставить и в том же PyCharm (если он есть на Linux) можно выбрать версию которая нужна

Comment: А зачем? Чтобы половина старых системных скриптов перестала работать?

Comment: С одной стороны лучше не ставить новую, т.к. как вы говорите половина скриптов работать не будет. Но с другой стороны в новых версиях много нового добавляют. Решать вам)

Comment: Чтобы я начал писать что-то свое на питоне, в него сначала надо добавить хотя бы фигурные скобочки -) (ну, вы поняли, не для множеств, а для структуры блоков кода) (хотя, тот же 3.10 уже сделал шаг в правильном направлении, добавили typing)

Comment: Ну что могу сказать, крепитесь:)

Comment: Но мне хватает обычного Си (и sed-a с grep-ом -))

Comment: Третий вариант для `elif(q==1 or q==0):` ->  `if q in 0, 1:`

Answer (score 3):

```
print('Типа психологический тест на созависимость')
print('Отвечайте только "Да" или "Нет"')
# Создаём список с вопросами, которые необходимо задать
questions = [
    'Вам легко знакомиться с людьми?: ',
    'Вы бы хотели быть в центре внимания других людей?: ',
    'Вам трудно принимать решения?: ',
    'Вы часто тревожитесь?: ',
]
points = 0
# С помощью цикла for по очереди задаём вопросы из нашего списка
for question in questions:
    x = input(question)
    # Такой цикл while проверяет что-бы ответ был только 'да' или 'нет'
    while x.lower() not in ('да', 'нет'):
        print('Такого варианта ответа нет!')
        x = input(question)
    if x.lower() == 'да':
        points += 1
    elif x.lower() == 'нет':
        points += 0

if points == 4:
    print("Вы созависимый человек")
elif points == 3:
    print("Вы местами созависимы")
elif points == 2:
    print("Вам стоит поработать над собой")
else:
    print("Вы несозависимы!")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: nsw = ["Вы несозависимы!", "Вам стоит поработать над собой", "Вы местами созависимы", "Вы созависимый человек"]
    print(nsw[points-1]